# How to resize a 3D image in a keras CNN model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, resize, batchsize

I have a 3D PET scan (None, 128, 128, 60, 1). I want to resize it to be (None, 64, 64, 30, 1). Sometimes I need it to be even smaller. I want to do this inside a keras model. I was thinking of something like tf.image.resize but for 3D images.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the last dimension of the 3D image `( None , 128 , 128 , 60 , 1)`  so that the shape of the transformed tensor is `( None , 128 , 128 , 60 )` that matches with the required shape for [`tf.image`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize) which is `( height , width , channels )`. ( **Note: the required shape can also be `( batch_size , height, width, num_channels )`** )

We will use [`tf.squeeze`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) for this purpose.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Some random image
image = tf.random.normal( shape=( 128 , 128 , 60 , 1 ) )
# Remove dimensions of size 1 from `image`
image = tf.squeeze( image )
# Resize the image
resized_image = tf.image.resize( image , size=( 100 , 100 ) )
print( tf.shape( resized_image ) )
```

The output

```
tf.Tensor([100 100  60], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

To restore the deleted dimension of size `1`, you may use `tf.expand_dims`,

```py
resized_image = tf.expand_dims( resized_image , axis=3 )
print( tf.shape( resized_image ))
```

The output,

```
tf.Tensor([100 100  60   1], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Using this method, I can resize the first two dimensions of the scan, but how would I change the third dimension that has the value 60? I want to change 60 to be 30. In you example, 60 continued to be 60.

Comment: You may then need to select 30 channels out those 60 channels manually.